# find a value in a dataframe and add precedent column value in a new column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data frame with 5 columns, I need to check specific string("-") in all columns and add precedent value in new column(F) if "-" is found. for example, "-" is located in Column B row zero and two; hence, 'a' and 'c'[precedent Column value] are added in Column(F) in related rows and so on.

Source Data Frame:

[image]

Desired Data Frame would be:

[image]

I have written below codes but get value length error when I want to create new Column(F), appreciate your support.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
 'B': {0: '-', 1: 'a', 2: '-', 3: 'b', 4: 'd'}})

df['C'] = np.where(df['B'].isin(df['A'].values), df['B'], np.nan)
df['C'] = df['C'].map(dict(zip(df.A.values, df.B.values)))
df['D'] = np.where(df['C'].isin(df['B'].values), df['C'], np.nan)
df['D'] = df['D'].map(dict(zip(df.B.values, df['C'].values)))
df['E'] = np.where(df['D'].isin(df['C'].values), df['D'], np.nan)
df['E'] = df['E'].map(dict(zip(df['C'].values, df['D'].values)))

a=np.array(df.iloc[:,:5])
g=[]
for index,x in np.ndenumerate(a):
    temp=[]
    if x=="-":
        temp.append(x-1)
    g.append(temp)
df['F']=g
print(df)
```

Comment: what if you have a row with two dashes. What will F value be?

Comment: There is no such value in the dataframe,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace misisng values to all columns by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) exclude previous values by `-` compared by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed values, then back filling missing values and select first column by position:

```
df['F'] = df.where(df.shift(-1, axis=1).eq('-')).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
   A  B    F
0  a  -    a
1  b  a  NaN
2  c  -    c
3  d  b  NaN
4  e  d  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['F']=[i[0][-1] if len(i)>1 else np.nan for i in df.fillna('').sum(axis=1).str.split('-') ]
```

output:

```
df['F']
Out[41]: 
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    a
4    a
Name: F, dtype: object
```

List Comprehension Explanation:

- fill the NAs in df with '' and `sum` it across `rows`
- split the sum with `-`
- select the first element after spliting with `-` if length is > 1, else `-` wont be present hence fill with `np.nan`
- select the last element of the splitted data by using `[-1]`